# Make timed loop by microsecond in C

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi

I wanted to make like:

```
   int prev = 0;
   int delay = 1500;
   void loop(){
       int now = micros();
       if(now - prev > delay){
           //
       }
   }
```

That is for Arduino. 
How do I make with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &gettime_now);` in C working like `micros()` in arduino code above? In Raspberry pi

Comment: Your example code makes little sense. Like, why is function name "loop" when there is no loop?

Comment: @hyde It's Arduino nonsense. I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really use busy polling the clock in a C program, it's a system call. It's fitting for a µController but less so for an OS. You could just use usleep.

Anyhow clock_gettime timespec so just do careful computation (watching out not to overflow your longs).
(long) (now.tv_sec - prev.tv_sec)*1000*1000 + (now.tv_nsec - prev.tv_nsec)/1000

P.S.
Shouldn't you initialise prev in your code?